# VBS - Copy Specific Files From Path

Tags: vbscript

I have been through a few code samples to get the desired result, however, since I am currently making use of the below code (slightly modified) for another purpose, I thought it would work great for this too.

At line 42 I get the error:

> The specified network name is no longer available

Line 42: `For Each objFile In objFolder.Files`

```
' Require variables to be defined
Option Explicit

' Global variables
Dim strBaseFolder
Dim strDestFolder
Dim objFSO      
Dim objFolder
Dim objFile
Dim searchname1, searchname2, searchname3, searchname4, searchname5

' Define folders to work with
strBaseFolder = "X:\Source\Data"
strDestFolder = "X:\Test\Terminations"

searchname1 = "MyFile"
searchname2 = "YourFile"
searchname3 = "HerFile"
searchname4 = "HisFile"
searchname5 = "OurFile"

' Create filesystem object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Exit if base folder does not exist
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strBaseFolder) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Missing base folder : """ & strBaseFolder & """"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

' Exit if dest folder does not exist
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDestFolder) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Missing dest folder : """ & strDestFolder & """"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

' Look at each subfolder of base folder
For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strBaseFolder).SubFolders
    ' Continue if we want this folder

        ' Check each file in this folder
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            ' Continue if we want this file
            If IncludeFile(objFile) Then
                ' Copy the file
                objFSO.copyFile objFile, strDestFolder & "\" & objFile.Name
            End If
        Next

Next

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    wscript.echo "Files Seccuessfully Copied"

Else If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    wscript.echo "An Error Occurred"

End If

End If

' Logic to determine if we process a file
Function IncludeFile(objFile)
    IncludeFile = False
    Select Case LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path))
        ' Include only these extensions
        Case "csv", "xls", "xlsx", "txt"
            ' Include only files dated today
            if instr(objFile, searchname1) = 1 or instr(objFile, searchname2) = 1  or instr(objFile, searchname3) = 1  or instr(objFile, searchname4) = 1 or instr(objFile, searchname5) = 1 then
                IncludeFile = True 
            end if
    End Select
End Function
```

I don't understand this because I can manually go into the share and copy the files and if I run a different script accessing the same share, then it works great..

Comment: What is the different script accessing the same share?

Comment: Apologies for taking long to reply @omegastripes. I don't have the script I was referring to anymore, however, I have a working script that i am using now. I have posted the answer below. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question above:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("X:\\Data\")
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 
        fileName=objFile.name 
    If instr(fileName,"MyFile") Then
        FSO.copyfile objFile, "X:\Test\Other Files" & "\", True
    End If

    If instr(fileName,"YourFIle") Then
        FSO.copyfile objFile, "X:\Test\3rd Party" & "\", True
    End If

    If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "txt" Then

        If instr(fileName,"OurFile") Then
            FSO.copyfile objFile, "X:\Test\Other Files" & "\", True
        End If

        If instr(fileName,"TheirFile") Then
            FSO.copyfile objFile, "X:\Test\Other Files" & "\", True
        End If

        If instr(fileName,"someFile") Then
            FSO.copyfile objFile, "X:\Test\Other Files" & "\", True
        End If

    End If

Next

If Err.Number > 0 Then

    WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear

  Else

  WScript.Echo "Other Files Copied!"

End If
```

Comment: Have you tried to use wildcards `*` and `?` in filenames? Also you might use `Shell.Application` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen if there is a hidden or system subfolder that you don't have permission to read. Check by dumping the names of the folders to the console from your script, see which one it chokes on, then see if you can see that folder from explorer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Glen. I did check this, it was not the issue. However, thank you for your help. I have since got the answer needed and I have posted it below.